# How to handle domain changes in a event sourced application?

Tags: scala, event-sourcing

I'm currently using Scala and [Eventuate](http://rbmhtechnology.github.io/eventuate/), but I think this question applies to any event sourced environment:

Let’s say you have the following event: `case class UserAdded(user: User)`, and `User` is `case class User(username:String, birthday: Date)`.

Your app has been running for a while and now you need to collect the Users' phone number. So now we would need to change `User` to `case class User(username:String, birthday: Date, phoneNumber: String)`.

When the events are replayed, it will throw errors because past events didn't have a `phoneNumber`. How do you usually address this problem in a event-sourced application?

My first thought was to set a default value for all the events in the event store, but I understand events are immutable when you do event sourcing, so I decided to hear from more experienced users on the matter.

Any input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is known as "versioning" in event sourcing and, despite the fact that event sourcing is a relative new technology,  there are at least two solutions:

1. You keep  the old event (class and data) and introduce a new event type for future events like `class UserAddedV2(username:String, birthday: Date, phoneNumber: String)`. This has the disadvantage that the old class will continue to exist although it is not instantiated any more.
2. You migrate your entire stream of events and replace the old event with a new one, with a default value for the new field. In this way you get rid of old event classes.

I strongly recommend Greg Young's [book](https://leanpub.com/esversioning/read) as it is the best I ever found on this topic.

Comment: I think that admitting the possibility of rewriting the event stream is a slipper slope: before you know it, every other deployment will require a history rewrite.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin  Events tie the data to the code in such a strong way that only a history rewrite can break that coupling, IMHO. Anyway, one should at least know about this tactical pattern

Comment: Awesome book! I didn't know of it. It covers the problem in depth, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I think there are two conceptual mistakes here.

First, an event shouldn't "reference" or "contain" a domain object. An event is a record of what happened, and so it should explicitly record the data points that characterize it. In this case - `username` and `birthday`:

```
case class UserAdded(username:String, birthday: Date)
```

Now, this event definition can never, ever change. What happened, happened. There is no rewriting the past.

If, at a certain point, business requirements change, this means that from now on a *different* kind of event will happen:

```
case class UserAdded2(username:String, birthday: Date, phoneNumber: String)
```

Both events should stay intact, both should be handled, processed, whatever. The first event is not "useless now", as intuition might suggest. Quite the opposite: the first event records what was happening before the requirements changed, and that record is valuable.

Now, depending on what your platform allows (I'm unfamiliar with Eventuate), you might be able to technically implement both events as a single class with an optional field. But even if you do, you should always remember that this class represents two different events. For this reason, I would rather prefer them to be explicitly defined as separate things.